# Disable code autocompletion in JS files

Tags: javascript, web-mode

For some reason, my Emacs started autocompleting code. I have noticed this in both web-mode and rjsx-mode. For example, if I type `<button></` it will autocomplete it to `<button></button>` and move my cursor back.

I want to entirely disable this autocompletion.

I can't figure out what is causing the autocomplete. I was searching online and found references to company-mode and auto-complete-mode but neither of those seem to exist in my Emacs.

Here's my .emacs file in case it's helpful.

```
;; zenburn theme
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")
(load-theme 'zenburn t)

;; nyan-mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/nyan-mode")
(require 'nyan-mode)
(nyan-mode 1)

;; melpa
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(package-selected-packages '(rjsx-mode web-mode slime)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; slime
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")

;; tabs/indentation
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)

(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for web-mode"
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing nil))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'my-web-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I just figured it out, it has to do with rjsx-mode.

```
(eval-after-load 'rjsx-mode
  '(progn
     (define-key rjsx-mode-map "<" nil)))
```

This disables it.

I got confused because I used `M-x web-mode` while I was in rjsx-mode, I guess that doesn't disable the first mode.

Comment: There will usually be many *minor* modes active in a buffer, but there is only ever one major mode active at any time.  `web-mode` is certainly a major mode (I don't know anything about `rjsx-mode`).  Calling a major mode will also cause the buffer's minor modes to be re-established (so that list may change).

Comment: FYI you can write that as `(with-eval-after-load 'rjsx-mode (define-key rjsx-mode-map "<" nil))` which tends to look slightly cleaner.  Note the different macro name, and no need for the quote or `progn` (this macro allows you to evaluate multiple forms without a progn wrapper).